# If $\limsup_n\sqrt[n]{a_n}=\frac{1}{r}$, then $\limsup_n\sqrt[n]{(n+1)a_{n+1}}=?$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, limsup-and-liminf

> If $\limsup_n\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=\frac{1}{r}$, then $\limsup_n\sqrt[n]{|(n+1)a_{n+1}|}=?$

Can I separate the product of the second limit as $$\limsup_n\sqrt[n]{|(n+1)a_{n+1}|}=\limsup_n\sqrt[n]{(n+1)}\limsup_n\sqrt[n]{|a_{n+1}|}$$since the first limit exists and $\sqrt[n]{(n+1)}$ is bounded, if not does the RHS majorize LHS, so that I deduce the limit is also $\frac{1}{r}$

(Original Exercise: If $\sum_na_nz^n$ has radius of convergence $r$, so has $\sum_n na_nz^{n-1}$)

Comment: Sorry, broke my rule and answered before I read the question.

Comment: It is not true in general that if $a_n,b_n$ are sequences, then $\limsup a_nb_n = (\limsup a_n)(\limsup b_n)$. But if $a_n$ converges to a positive value, it is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **not true**, in general, that if $x_n,y_n$ are sequences, then $$\limsup x_ny_n = (\limsup x_n)(\limsup y_n).$$

For example, if $$x_n=\begin{cases}1&n\text{ even}\\2&n\text{ odd}\end{cases}$$ and $y_n=\frac{2}{x_n}$, then $\limsup x_n=\limsup y_n = 2$, but $\limsup x_ny_n = 2\neq 2\cdot 2$.

But if $x_n$ converges to a positive value, it is true.

Comment: But If I go back to the question, in my equation $=$ must be raplaced by $\le$, and RHS converges to $1/r$, how can I show that LHS also converges to the same value, is there an $N$ s.t. $\sqrt[n]{(n+1)a_{n+1}}\ge\sqrt[n]{a_n}$ for $n\ge N$ ?

Comment: Be more specific. LHS of what? RHS of what? You need to know the theorem I stated in the last line - that your step is allowed when one of $x_n$ or $y_n$ is convergent to a positive value.

Comment: So normally $\limsup_n\sqrt[n]{|(n+1)a_{n+1}|}\color{red}{\le}   \limsup_n\sqrt[n]{(n+1)}\limsup_n\sqrt[n]{|a_{n+1}|}$ but since  $\limsup_n\sqrt[n]{(n+1)}=1\implies \limsup_n\sqrt[n]{|(n+1)a_{n+1}|}\color{red}{=}\limsup_n\sqrt[n]{(n+1)}\limsup_n\sqrt[n]{|a_{n+1}|}$ and hence $\limsup_n\sqrt[n]{|(n+1)a_{n+1}|}=\frac1{r}$ ?

Comment: It has nothing to do with $\limsup_n \sqrt[n]{n+1}=1$. It has to do with the fact that $\lim_n \sqrt[n]{n+1}=1$ and $1>0$.